# В каких случаях метод ActiveRecord save() возвращает false?

Tags: php, yii2

У меня с товарищем возникла дискуссия вот по какому поводу:

Насколько целесообразно проверять `if ($model->save())` , если мы точно знаем что правила валидации у нас соблюдены, и внутри метода `save()` метод `validate()` всегда будет возвращать `true`?

Хотелось бы точно разобрать все случаи, когда метод `save()` возвращает `false`.
Пока что я вижу только два момента:

1. Не прошла валидация.
2. Произошла ошибка в методе `beforeSave()`.

Comment: На самом деле это не важно, что и где могло произойти. Проверять надо всегда. Может коннект к БД отвалился, может памяти мало или таймаут и т.д.

Comment: @fedornabilkin, нет это важно, я хочу точно понимать что происходит в моём коде. Я с вами полностью согласен, что нужно проверять, но вопрос ведь не в том, нужно ли проверять или нет, а в том - в каких случаях метод возвратит `false`.